# Rounded Window Corners with Themes not Working

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.04, themes, gtk

I am trying to use themes on Ubuntu (14.04) Unity and I am having some issues with that themes are not looking like they are supposed to look. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Theme probs]

Notice that the top bar of the window does not have rounded corners and that the menu bar menus look odd.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so already I would suggest doing the following:

- Install unity-tweak-tool
- Check the GTK theme and Window Decoration that you have in place -
  Doing this may highlight a mismatch or that the wrong themes are
  active

If that does not work could I ask the details of the theme you expected to be present?

Comment: Aright so I already have `unity-tweak-tool`. It is how I am switching themes (I'm not doing it through the regular dialog). How do I check the GTK theme and window decoration?

Comment: I don't do it from the regular system dialogue (`System Settings -> Appearance`) because the themes do not show up there for some reason. The themes I believe are installed in `/usr/share/themes`

Comment: I do notice that some of the themes that do work are ones with a `Unity` folder within the theme directory, although the theme with the issue in the question does have one. Could this be related at all? For example, `Adwaita OSX` does not have the `Unity` folder, and the entire UI looks broken.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that looking at the creators comments on the Deviant Art page  for Adwaita OSX
http://kxmylo.deviantart.com/art/Adwaita-OS-X-432018151?offset=10#comments

that this theme is not supported in Unity and this may be causing the problem

Comment: The issue is that it is not only Adwaita OSX that has issues. Innumerable other themes also seem to not be working; in fact, it seems I can only get the default theme to look the way it is supposed to.

Comment: oh and Numix also looks normal. That's about it.